# SCCM 2012 | Collection Query | Auto Add Machines but they should not be present in other collection

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

I have three collections SCCM 2012:

1. Global Domain - Test (I have two machines here already)
2. Global Domain - 1 (i have 10 machines here already)
3. Global Domain - 2 (Query should automatically add machine here)

I need your help in creating a query, for the collection "Global Domain - 2".

What the query has to do is,

1. Find all the machines with the naming convention "SVDS"
2. Ensure the machine that are already present in the collection "Global Domain - Test" and "Global Domain - 1" are skipped
3. Add the rest to "Global Domain - 2"

Can you help with the query please ?

**My query:**

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where SMS_R_System.SystemOUName = "somthing.com/DOMAIN"
```

Question is How to exclude the machines which are already member of "Global Domain - Test" and "Global Domain - 1"

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Exclude Collections** rule (now part of SCCM 2012) and exclude collections "Global Domain - Test" and "Global Domain - 1" from your "Global Domain - 2" device collection.

Adding the 2 exclude rules will exclude any child members, even if they are targeted by the "Global Domain - 2" query.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2012/04/24/include-exclude-collections-rule.aspx